# What's wrong in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

LIVE CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/nnMYN/

I have to "automatically copy the postal address to the home address field if a user checks the "Same as above" checkbox. In addition to this, we'll disable the home address field when the checkbox is checked." ([from here](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Web_Design/JavaScript_Challenges#Challenge_2%3a_.27Same_as_above.27_Postal_Address_boxes)) What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <fieldset>

                <legend>Billing Information</legend>

                <p>
                    <label>
                        Postal Address:<br>
                        <textarea name="postaladdress" id="postaladdress"></textarea>
                    </label>
                </p>

                <p>
                    Home Address:<br>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="homepostalcheck" id="homepostalcheck">
                        Same as above
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <textarea name="homeaddress" id="homeaddress"></textarea>
                </p>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var loc = document.getElementById('homepostalcheck');
            var home = document.getElementById('homeaddress');
            loc.onclick = !loc.checked ? function() {home.disabled = true; home.value = post.value; alert(post.value);} : function() {home.disabled = false; home.select();};
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
var post = document.getElementById('postaladdress');
```

You keep trying to access the parameter `value` of the `post` object, but there is no such `post` object because you haven't defined it. If you add the above line after your definition of `home`, you should be set! It worked when I edited it on jsFiddle.

Comment: That didn't completely work, but I found a solution. But thanks, that certainly helped me. Working version: http://jsfiddle.net/nnMYN/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the javascript in function() {

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var loc = document.getElementById('homepostalcheck');
        var home = document.getElementById('homeaddress');
        loc.onclick = !loc.checked ? function() {home.disabled = true; home.value = post.value; alert(post.value);} : function() {home.disabled = false; home.select();};
    });
</script>
```